# set datepicker date on textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using core data to add an entity to a database. There is a field for calculating your age. You use the picker to fill out your birthday and it sets the text of the textfield according to what was selected in the datepicker. There is another view, a detail view of the entity which you can edit. Unfortunately, when the picker loads, it loads todays date, and not the date in the textfield that was already set. Is there any way I can set the picker's date using a textfield? The text is in this format: August 11, 1997. Sorry if I explained poorly. Basically I want to set the datepicker's date based upon the text in a textfield.

just so you have an idea of what is happening:

```
- (void) dateChanged:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    birthdayTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                   [dateFormatter stringFromDate:birthdayDatePicker.date]];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *startdate= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [dateFormatter stringFromDate: birthdayDatePicker.date]];

    NSDate *End=[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit
                                                        fromDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:startdate]
                                                          toDate:End
                                                         options:0];
    if(components.year > 0){
    ageTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",components.year];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which text field contains the date that needs to be shown on date pikcer birthdayTextField or ageTextField? and provide the code where you are showing date picker

Comment: birthdayTextField displays the date in the following format: "August 11, 1997". What do you mean by: where you are showing the date picker?

Comment: please provide the code where you are showing your date picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated
```

is the function to set the date on the date picker. So now you need to pass the date set in the text field as a date object using NSDate. If the input to the text field was a string then you could do this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"09-08-2013";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Now pass this to the first function. Hope this helped.

Comment: is there anyway to set the date format like this: "January 1, 1997"? or do I need to convert it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateFormatterMediumStyle should help you out here.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    CGSize pickerSize = [datePicker sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
     pickerToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0,200, 320, 44);

    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 244, pickerSize.width, 460);
    datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];

- (void) dateChanged:(id)sender
{
 NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
birthdayTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                   [dateFormatter stringFromDate:birthdayDatePicker.date]];
}
```

Hope This Works For You....

Comment: its working great for me!! but one advice, instead of                          [self.view addSubview:datePicker];
u can put     [self.urtextfield setInputView:datePicker]; when if you want to display once user clicks the textfield and you can after selecting the date for hiding the datepicker in the method end of                           - (void) dateChanged:(id)sender                                 
   [self.urtextfield resignFirstResponder];, i hope this will helps to others

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
      dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
      NSDate *exampleDateFromString =[dateFormat dateFromString:@"8:48 AM"]; 
      date-picker.minimumDate=exampleDateFromString;
     [date-picker setDate:exampleDateFromString];
```